# Pythonic way to start an iterator from an specific index

Tags: python, iterator, pytorch

I'm trying to change [this code](https://github.com/sergeytulyakov/mocogan/blob/master/src/trainers.py) so the iterator in the function `sample_real_video_batch` in line `142` would start from a specific batch number (as opposed to start of the dataset).
Here is the function:

```
def sample_real_video_batch(self):
    if self.video_enumerator is None:
        self.video_enumerator = enumerate(self.video_sampler)

    batch_idx, batch = next(self.video_enumerator)
    b = batch
    if self.use_cuda:
        for k, v in batch.iteritems():
            b[k] = v.cuda()

    if batch_idx == len(self.video_sampler) - 1:
        self.video_enumerator = enumerate(self.video_sampler)

    return b
```

An obvious and very inefficient approach would be to call the function in a loop for `n` times. But generally speaking, is there an efficient way to start the iterator off a specific index in python?

And is it applicable to pytorch `ImageDataset`?

Comment: Please post your code as *text* here. It is easier for you and us to copy-paste than a photo/link to code; more importantly, no risk of dead links.

Comment: @Austin Thanks for your comment, I've added the code.

Comment: Would not you want to pass in an index and slice `self.video_sampler`?

Comment: @Austin `self.video_sampler` is a an instance of a subclass of `torch.utils.data.Dataset`. I'm not sure how to slice a dataset object.

Comment: You can use `itertools.islice` to consume a specific number of elements from an iterator.

Comment: @PaulM. That did the trick. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul M mentioned in the comments, `itertools.islice()` can be used to consume a specific slice of elements.

As for the second part of my question, apparently the only way is to use a `SequentialSampler` which is used by default when `shuffle=False` in a pytorch `DataLoader`. So one needs to first create a `SequentialSampler` with the portion of dataset in mind, and then a regular `Dataloader` for the rest of the data.